# Named entity recognition

Tags: machine-learning, text, natural-language

How can one process natural language (English) to extract named entities (aka NER)? Or at least, entities which can be mapped to a Mathematica Entity. Note that trying to map entities via simple tokenization, POS or  the dependency tree is not the same as NER. Also, I am aware that one can use neural networks to train NER but I would hope there is an easier solution within Mathematica.

Comment: Mathematica 12 will [support NER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdxRASPvyfE&feature=youtu.be&t=667). Coming soon.

Comment: I've encountered this problem too. In my case, it was sufficient to look for capitalised words within a sentence, or the first word returning `WordData` a its head instead of `List` on POS queries. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Partial answer: (1) you can use R within Mathematica, and R has several packages for NER; (2) you can use `JLink` and connect to, say, the [Java Stanford NER library](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html). (And with the results from those do `Entity` mapping...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Mathematica v12 has indeed named entity recognition via the `TextContents` command. [Details in the documentation.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextContents.html)