# How to train custom named entity recognition?

Tags: neural-networks, text, nlp, string-manipulation

Version 12 has basic NER support for some entities, **but how does one recognize a custom entity?**

For example, I want to parse text describing products, and parse out three entities: prices, size, and color, as custom entities. Using `TextCases` and `TextContents` works nicely for price and color:

```
TextCases["A red tshirt costs $5 and is medium", {"Color", 
  "CurrencyAmount"}]
```

[image]

But there is no way to parse entities that are not listed in `guide/TextContentTypes`, like sizes:

```
TextCases["large women's leather jacket", {"Size"}]
```

[image]

And there is no way to add additional synonyms or spellings to an entity:

```
TextCases[# <> " feather", "Color"] & /@ {"violet", "lilac", 
  "lavender", "royal", "purpled", "plum", "grape", "maroon", 
  "magenta", "purplish"}
```

[image]

I want to extend the built-in NER model with custom training data, i.e. substring labels:

```
newTrainingData = <|"Who is Nishanth?"-> {8, 16, "Name"},
"Who is Kamal Khumar?" -> {8, 20, "Name"},
"I like London and Berlin." -> {{8,14, "City"}, {19,25,"City"}
|>
```

If this is not supported in 12.2, perhaps there is a 3rd party paclet, resource function, or some NN repo entry to extend? or maybe it's coming in 12.3?

**Related:**

- Custom NER can be done in python with spacy: https://towardsdatascience.com/train-ner-with-custom-training-data-using-spacy-525ce748fab7
- Original post: [Named entity recognition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193300/named-entity-recognition)

Comment: There was some discussion of upcoming improvements to TextCases in a recent "Live CEOing" discussion (Ep 438 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Beccqss0nGw around 1:16) and its entity recognition performance. Those in the system entity framework should be more reliably identified by TextCases but I don't think there are immediate plans to expose the machinery behind it to users for custom entity type creation.